# How to see Maven console in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In Eclipse one could see the maven build log by going to `Console` window, clicking new and then selecting `Maven Console`.

[image]

How could I see maven log output in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you configure a Maven Launch-Configuration and execute it the according Maven build output will be displayed in the `Run`-Tab by default:

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Note: There is a Tab `Logs` where you can configure additional log relevant settings such as logging to a file).

If you dont like to setup a Run-Configuration for each Maven build (in Intellij as it seems you cant just right click a `pom.xml` and click `run as...`) you can call Maven directly from the Tab `Terminal`

[image]

(Note: In my scenario the system variable `M2_HOME` was set to the maven installation directory and added to the windows `PATH` variable - after that you can run `mvn` from any directory - especially from directories containing `pom.xml` files)

Comment: Is this possible when doing Right Click on Project -> Maven -> Reimport ? Some of the dependencies are not being resolved and I want to see why.

Comment: This is only half the answer. What happens to the maven logging from the internal Intellij dependencies processing when you change a `pom.xml` for instance?

Comment: The "Run" window is never displayed after add a Maven configuration with the default values (do I seriously have to hard-code the project root path into the configuration - "Intelli"J can't figure this out on its own?). I doubt the configuration is added, but I don't get any feedback from the UI. Where would I have to search for the information whether the configuration is added or not that I should be provided with automatically? You sure this has left alpha stadium already?

Answer (score 0):

IDEA is calling Maven via API so there is no regular console output available.

see:[intellij-support-forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000084024-Can-I-get-console-output-from-maven-when-downloading-artifacts-)

Comment: this forum post says that you cannot see the output for IDEA calling maven to *download* artifacts, but the question was how to see the output of a maven *build* - that's different. See the accepted answer. Please consider deleting your answer, since it doesn't really provide a valid input.

Comment: @SimonA No it is not calling it via API (as a Java method call that is). The source you've linked to is incorrect as well. If you look at the first line in the console output it will show the commandline arguments used to invoke maven. You can copy paste this line into a terminal to get exact same result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with seeing no console output.

Reason was, I  had a non-existing JRE in my Maven configuration, and running Maven from the Maven toolbar opened neither the Run tab nor displayed any kind of error message.

Check: Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner > JRE